# Conditional statements in jquery for button status?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I'm new to JQuery. I want to put a conditional statement in my script but I'm not sure of the syntax for button effects. I wan't it along the lines of

**if ".save" = .show then .hide ".donedit"**

This script is for a table, I don't want users to be able to click the .donedit button if they have edited a field without saving the content.

Right now The .save button shows only when a user has edited a field, the ideal function would be to grey out or hide the donedit button if the .save button is showing.

Here's the relevant piece:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //individual field edit buttons show as hidden     
        $(".edit").hide();
        $(".donedit").hide();


       //when the mass edit button is clicked in the header, the edit button 
       //will show for each field, the massedit button will hide showing the donedit button 

       $(".massedit").click(function(){
             $(".edit").show();
             $(".massedit").hide();
             $(".donedit").show();
        });

       //When the donedit button is clicked the massedit button shows and the
       // donedit button disappears 

       $(".donedit").click(function(){
             $(".edit").hide();
             $(".massedit").show();
             $(".donedit").hide();               
       });

   });
```

Comment: show some html bro

Answer (score 0):

If you are using show and hide you can do

```
$(".save").css("display")
```

and if it returns "block" that means it is currently being shown, and if it returns "none" then it is currently hidden. So you can just check if:

```
if ($(".save").css("display") != "none") {
  //donedit button code can run
}
```

That isn't a great way to do it since you are asking the DOM for the state instead of just storing whether or not ".save" is hidden or not, but it is probably the easiest solution.

EDIT:

You can even throw in an else statement if you want and alert the user that they are trying to close editing without saving, or use confirm and if it returns true then let them close without saving

Or better yet just change the code to

```
if ($(".save").css("display") != "none" && confirm("Continue without saving")) {
  //donedit button code can run
}
```